# Can I make a shortcut to the main system keyboard in my custom keyboard extension?

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard

From an iOS custom keyboard extension, I'd like a shortcut button to the main ABC system keyboard. NOT just to advance to the next keyboard. Is this possible? If so, how?

Note: This is not a 'how do I do it' question, it's a theoretical question whether it's possible. Currently, iOS necessitates an 'advance to next keyboard' button for all custom keyboard extensions. As far as I can tell, there doesn't seem to be a way to access/shortcut to just the main system keyboard. [handleInputModeList(from:with:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiinputviewcontroller/1649584-handleinputmodelist)

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Magnas I provided an edit, any suggestions on how to write this question better?